# Communicate between a Web page/app and a Browser Extension

Tags: javascript, web-applications, cross-browser, browser-extension

I have a Web App and an associated Browser Extension and I need a way of communication information from the Web App to the Extension when an action occurs in the Web App.

Chrome has runtime.onMessageExternal() etc. which lets your app or extension  receive and respond to messages from regular web pages. ref: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

This should meet my needs, however it isn't available in Firefox and I need a cross browser solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with content script. Messaging from content script support by FF from version 50.